# jQuery hover effect for ::after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm firing several effects when I hover over a div. The problem is that the div also has the pseudo element ::after, which populates the div with a virtual element (a play button) using the content CSS rule.

My hover effects work when I'm hovering any part of the div other than the space where the ::after element is.

Simply, I want to know if there is a way to point towards the ::after element using jQuery. I've tried to define the ::after element as a variable named "play", but have had no luck there either. This is my script:

```
var play = $('a.image-wrap::after');

$(".image-holder, .big-headline a, .small-headline a, play").on({mouseenter: function () {
      $('.image-holder').css('background-color', color);
      $('.image-holder img').css({
        'mix-blend-mode': 'multiply',
        opacity: .6
      });
      if ($(window).width() > 1115) {
        $('.read').css('right', '35%');
      } else {
        $('.read').css('right', '0');
      }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $('.image-holder').css('background-color', '');
      $('.image-holder img').css({
        'mix-blend-mode': '',
        opacity: ''
      });
      $('.read').css('right', '');
    }
  });
```

Comment: better handle it in css not jquery

Comment: You can't access ::after, ::before using js. You should use css and transform

Comment: why not add a class to the parent element then you can target that: eg `.hovering:hover:after`

Comment: @Pete Yes, but I need a number of other effects to fire on other divs when that element is being hovered. How can I tell other elements to act in CSS when that os being hovered?

Comment: The way I would do it is toggle a class on all the divs that you are wanting to add effects to, that way you can just style those classes for the hover states - https://jsfiddle.net/otgsfh2q/1

Answer (score 0):

What if you just add the new CSS to a style and then remove it when we're done hovering?  It works pretty well:

```js
$(".example").on("mouseenter", function () {
 $("#workAround").html(".example:after {background:pink}");
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
 $("#workAround").html("");
});
```

```css
.example {
 height:10px;
 width:100px;
 background:green;
 margin:20px 0 20px 0;
}

.example:after {
 content:'';
 background:red;
 height:10px;
 width:100%;
  display: block;
 position:relative;
 bottom:-10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="workAround"></style>
<div class="example"></div>
```