# Add hover:after with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am finding myself having problems with a simple css+jquery hover state. I have a list of elements:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="one">
    <span><h1>element oneA</h1></span>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <span><h1>element two</h1></span>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <span><h1>element three</h1></span>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <span><h1>element four</h1></span>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    <span><h1>element five</h1></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

The effect I want to achieve is hover on any of the elements and have the entire .list div move elegantly to the left. Because I want to apply the effect to the parent, I decided to use jquery instead of simple css. Which worked so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one, .two, .three, .four, .five").hover(
    function(){ $('.list').addClass("Mydivadd")},
    function(){ $('.list').removeClass('Mydivadd')}
  );
});
```

(the class I added being a change in position). The problem was that this option resulted in a lot of intense flickering. So I did some googling and I ran into this beautiful smooth transition, obviously adapted to my positioning needs:

```
.list .one
{
  transition: ease all 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}

.list .one:hover
{
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-20rem);
}
.lists .one:hover:after
{
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% + 20rem);
  position: absolute;
  right: -20rem;
}
```

which works perfectly but obviously only applies to one of the items inside the big div. So my question is: is there any way to add that hover:after css that prevents the flickering to my jquery function? I feel like the solution is obvious and right in front of me but I can't see it.

thank you very much in advance for your time, sorry for the long question :)

Comment: did you already saw this discussion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862188/jquery-hover-effect-for-after

Answer (score 0):

You can apply with jQuery only inline css. `:before` or `after` cannot set inline.

However,

If you want to add it to all items, do:

```
.lists>div:hover{...}
.lists>div:hover:after{...}
```

Or add a common class to all the items, and replace the `.one` to that class in the css

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working, I still get a lot of flicker

Comment: What you want to happen? to give this styles to the active item, or all of them?

Comment: If you want it to all, just select `.lists>div..` or give  a common class to all the item and use it